# Parsing a data table with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have grabbed data from an internal network, it clearly pulls the data as I can see the XML content when I 'print' it.

```
ptdf_data1 = requests.get(r'https://zema.nam.nsroot.net:8443/datadirect/ZEData?command=LoadProfile&username=%(username)s&password=%(password)s&id=Citi&groupname=%(profile_group)s&profilename=%(profile_name)s&profileowner=%(profile_username)s&style=xml' % params, verify=False).content
```

I am trying to use beautiful soup to parse the data into the columns labeled below (each column will then have a list of lots of price data)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(ptdf_data1, "lxml")

ptdf_data = []

for ptdf_data_xml in soup.findAll(ptdf_data1):  # 'Pdtf'):  #
    dt = ptdf_data_xml.Date
    hr = ptdf_data_xml.CalendarHour
    row = ptdf_data_xml.RowNumber
    ram = ptdf_data_xml.RemainingAvailableMargin
    be = ptdf_data_xml.BE
    de = ptdf_data_xml.DE
    fr = ptdf_data_xml.FR
    nl = ptdf_data_xml.NL
    ptdf_data += [(
        int(row.text),  
        pytz.timezone('CET').localize(
            datetime.datetime.strptime(dt.text, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")) + 
            datetime.timedelta(hours=int(hr.text) - 1), 
        float(deat.text), 
        float(fr.text), 
        float(nl.text), 
        float(be.text), 
        float(ram.text))]

ptdf_data = pandas.DataFrame(data=ptdf_data, columns=['Row', 'DateTime', 'DE', 'FR', 'NL', 'BE', 'RAM'])
ptdf = ptdf_data.set_index('DateTime')
```

But I keep getting an empty dataframe just with the column labels.
As asked for the XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>1</IdNumber>
        <Series>a</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>DE</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>EPEX</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Power Spot Market Auction (Hourly)</DataReport>
        <Observation>Data Value(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Numerator>EUR</Numerator>
        <Denominator>MWh</Denominator>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Country</Caption><Label>Germany/Austria</Label><Value>Germany/Austria</Value></Attribute>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Data Type</Caption><Label>Price</Label><Value>Price</Value></Attribute>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>2</IdNumber>
        <Series>b</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>FR</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>EPEX</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Power Spot Market Auction (Hourly)</DataReport>
        <Observation>Data Value(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Numerator>EUR</Numerator>
        <Denominator>MWh</Denominator>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Country</Caption><Label>France</Label><Value>France</Value></Attribute>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Data Type</Caption><Label>Price</Label><Value>Price</Value></Attribute>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>3</IdNumber>
        <Series>c</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>CH</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>EPEX</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Power Spot Market Auction (Hourly)</DataReport>
        <Observation>Data Value(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Numerator>EUR</Numerator>
        <Denominator>MWh</Denominator>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Country</Caption><Label>Switzerland</Label><Value>Switzerland</Value></Attribute>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Data Type</Caption><Label>Price</Label><Value>Price</Value></Attribute>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>4</IdNumber>
        <Series>d</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>ES</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>OMEL</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Daily Market Hourly Prices</DataReport>
        <Observation>Spain Price(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>5</IdNumber>
        <Series>e</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>PT</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>OMEL</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Daily Market Hourly Prices</DataReport>
        <Observation>Portugal Price(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>6</IdNumber>
        <Series>f</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>CZ</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>OTE</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Day-Ahead Market CZ Result</DataReport>
        <Observation>Price(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>7</IdNumber>
        <Series>g</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>NL</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>APX</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>NL Power Day Ahead Market (Hourly)</DataReport>
        <Observation>Value(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Commodity>Energy</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Market Type</Caption><Label>prices</Label><Value>prices</Value></Attribute>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>8</IdNumber>
        <Series>h</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>BE</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>Belpex</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Daily Market Results Hourly</DataReport>
        <Observation>Price(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>9</IdNumber>
        <Series>i</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>IT</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>GME</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Day Ahead Electricity Market Price</DataReport>
        <Observation>Price(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Market</Caption><Label>MGP</Label><Value>MGP</Value></Attribute>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Zone</Caption><Label>PUN</Label><Value>PUN</Value></Attribute>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>10</IdNumber>
        <Series>j</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>IT NORD</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>GME</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Day Ahead Electricity Market Price</DataReport>
        <Observation>Price(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Market</Caption><Label>MGP</Label><Value>MGP</Value></Attribute>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Zone</Caption><Label>NORD</Label><Value>NORD<</Attribute>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>11</IdNumber>
        <Series>k</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>UK</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>N2EX</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Day Ahead Auction Market Prices</DataReport>
        <Observation>Price(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource>
        <IdNumber>12</IdNumber>
        <Series>l</Series>
        <DataSourceCaption>NP</DataSourceCaption>
        <DataSourceName>NordPool</DataSourceName>
        <DataReport>Elspot System Prices</DataReport>
        <Observation>Price(AVERAGE)</Observation>
        <Commodity>Electricity</Commodity>
        <Interval>Daily</Interval>
        <Attribute> <Caption>Currency</Caption><Label>EUR</Label><Value>EUR</Value></Attribute>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSourceData>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>02/24/2016</Date>
            <Result>23.951</Result>
            <Result>29.646</Result>
            <Result>33.317</Result>
            <Result>30.423</Result>
            <Result>30.423</Result>
            <Result>24.322</Result>
            <Result>27.563</Result>
            <Result>29.191</Result>
            <Result>36.183</Result>
            <Result>36.204</Result>
            <Result>35.935</Result>
            <Result>20.417</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-02-24</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>02/25/2016</Date>
            <Result>27.880</Result>
            <Result>29.561</Result>
            <Result>33.439</Result>
            <Result>26.921</Result>
            <Result>26.921</Result>
            <Result>27.616</Result>
            <Result>27.862</Result>
            <Result>28.705</Result>
            <Result>37.117</Result>
            <Result>36.999</Result>
            <Result>43.896</Result>
            <Result>25.886</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-02-25</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>02/26/2016</Date>
            <Result>27.834</Result>
            <Result>28.088</Result>
            <Result>32.744</Result>
            <Result>25.458</Result>
            <Result>24.902</Result>
            <Result>27.205</Result>
            <Result>28.088</Result>
            <Result>28.088</Result>
            <Result>37.323</Result>
            <Result>37.364</Result>
            <Result>34.400</Result>
            <Result>23.864</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-02-26</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>02/27/2016</Date>
            <Result>23.001</Result>
            <Result>23.251</Result>
            <Result>30.112</Result>
            <Result>5.792</Result>
            <Result>5.792</Result>
            <Result>22.696</Result>
            <Result>23.369</Result>
            <Result>23.363</Result>
            <Result>34.391</Result>
            <Result>33.768</Result>
            <Result>33.278</Result>
            <Result>19.640</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-02-27</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>02/28/2016</Date>
            <Result>18.337</Result>
            <Result>18.353</Result>
            <Result>18.763</Result>
            <Result>6.680</Result>
            <Result>6.680</Result>
            <Result>16.787</Result>
            <Result>18.858</Result>
            <Result>18.358</Result>
            <Result>27.882</Result>
            <Result>28.112</Result>
            <Result>34.258</Result>
            <Result>19.036</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-02-28</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>02/29/2016</Date>
            <Result>23.945</Result>
            <Result>27.753</Result>
            <Result>30.684</Result>
            <Result>21.115</Result>
            <Result>21.115</Result>
            <Result>23.410</Result>
            <Result>24.862</Result>
            <Result>27.766</Result>
            <Result>33.336</Result>
            <Result>34.053</Result>
            <Result>33.157</Result>
            <Result>24.912</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-02-29</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/01/2016</Date>
            <Result>24.997</Result>
            <Result>31.256</Result>
            <Result>33.418</Result>
            <Result>29.462</Result>
            <Result>29.462</Result>
            <Result>23.577</Result>
            <Result>26.202</Result>
            <Result>30.936</Result>
            <Result>34.815</Result>
            <Result>34.790</Result>
            <Result>33.526</Result>
            <Result>20.572</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-01</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/02/2016</Date>
            <Result>24.049</Result>
            <Result>26.570</Result>
            <Result>33.094</Result>
            <Result>23.048</Result>
            <Result>23.048</Result>
            <Result>23.207</Result>
            <Result>26.442</Result>
            <Result>26.927</Result>
            <Result>35.016</Result>
            <Result>35.447</Result>
            <Result>33.089</Result>
            <Result>23.946</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-02</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/03/2016</Date>
            <Result>28.190</Result>
            <Result>29.252</Result>
            <Result>32.461</Result>
            <Result>25.596</Result>
            <Result>25.583</Result>
            <Result>28.197</Result>
            <Result>28.446</Result>
            <Result>29.229</Result>
            <Result>32.742</Result>
            <Result>34.482</Result>
            <Result>36.090</Result>
            <Result>25.562</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-03</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/04/2016</Date>
            <Result>24.884</Result>
            <Result>29.962</Result>
            <Result>32.458</Result>
            <Result>19.838</Result>
            <Result>19.838</Result>
            <Result>24.552</Result>
            <Result>26.717</Result>
            <Result>30.170</Result>
            <Result>35.557</Result>
            <Result>36.167</Result>
            <Result>33.620</Result>
            <Result>23.783</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-04</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/05/2016</Date>
            <Result>23.126</Result>
            <Result>24.118</Result>
            <Result>29.272</Result>
            <Result>10.682</Result>
            <Result>10.292</Result>
            <Result>22.049</Result>
            <Result>25.649</Result>
            <Result>24.699</Result>
            <Result>34.725</Result>
            <Result>34.641</Result>
            <Result>32.741</Result>
            <Result>20.102</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-05</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/06/2016</Date>
            <Result>21.334</Result>
            <Result>21.609</Result>
            <Result>21.653</Result>
            <Result>13.356</Result>
            <Result>13.115</Result>
            <Result>16.886</Result>
            <Result>21.610</Result>
            <Result>21.610</Result>
            <Result>34.651</Result>
            <Result>33.972</Result>
            <Result>34.074</Result>
            <Result>19.792</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-06</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/07/2016</Date>
            <Result>29.423</Result>
            <Result>32.991</Result>
            <Result>34.681</Result>
            <Result>25.289</Result>
            <Result>22.293</Result>
            <Result>28.658</Result>
            <Result>29.912</Result>
            <Result>32.236</Result>
            <Result>37.597</Result>
            <Result>37.622</Result>
            <Result>38.988</Result>
            <Result>23.452</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-07</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/08/2016</Date>
            <Result>28.364</Result>
            <Result>32.237</Result>
            <Result>35.737</Result>
            <Result>29.982</Result>
            <Result>29.943</Result>
            <Result>28.083</Result>
            <Result>28.434</Result>
            <Result>30.905</Result>
            <Result>39.336</Result>
            <Result>39.819</Result>
            <Result>35.519</Result>
            <Result>25.448</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-08</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/09/2016</Date>
            <Result>25.749</Result>
            <Result>27.745</Result>
            <Result>35.545</Result>
            <Result>21.462</Result>
            <Result>21.268</Result>
            <Result>25.025</Result>
            <Result>26.230</Result>
            <Result>27.421</Result>
            <Result>37.892</Result>
            <Result>37.571</Result>
            <Result>34.246</Result>
            <Result>24.275</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-09</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/10/2016</Date>
            <Result>26.155</Result>
            <Result>31.515</Result>
            <Result>34.400</Result>
            <Result>20.497</Result>
            <Result>20.497</Result>
            <Result>26.828</Result>
            <Result>27.535</Result>
            <Result>31.321</Result>
            <Result>40.087</Result>
            <Result>39.447</Result>
            <Result>38.510</Result>
            <Result>25.014</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-10</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/11/2016</Date>
            <Result>27.922</Result>
            <Result>29.680</Result>
            <Result>33.744</Result>
            <Result>30.865</Result>
            <Result>30.413</Result>
            <Result>26.663</Result>
            <Result>28.286</Result>
            <Result>29.578</Result>
            <Result>36.554</Result>
            <Result>36.599</Result>
            <Result>36.339</Result>
            <Result>26.737</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-11</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/12/2016</Date>
            <Result>27.815</Result>
            <Result>27.815</Result>
            <Result>25.409</Result>
            <Result>28.225</Result>
            <Result>28.225</Result>
            <Result>24.658</Result>
            <Result>27.815</Result>
            <Result>27.815</Result>
            <Result>34.741</Result>
            <Result>33.982</Result>
            <Result>33.138</Result>
            <Result>22.541</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-12</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/13/2016</Date>
            <Result>22.927</Result>
            <Result>22.738</Result>
            <Result>24.971</Result>
            <Result>24.054</Result>
            <Result>24.266</Result>
            <Result>20.809</Result>
            <Result>23.224</Result>
            <Result>22.601</Result>
            <Result>30.599</Result>
            <Result>30.447</Result>
            <Result>32.662</Result>
            <Result>21.515</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-13</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/14/2016</Date>
            <Result>27.455</Result>
            <Result>27.869</Result>
            <Result>32.355</Result>
            <Result>36.541</Result>
            <Result>36.456</Result>
            <Result>26.338</Result>
            <Result>27.509</Result>
            <Result>27.839</Result>
            <Result>34.130</Result>
            <Result>34.375</Result>
            <Result>34.230</Result>
            <Result>22.581</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-14</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/15/2016</Date>
            <Result>27.145</Result>
            <Result>29.675</Result>
            <Result>33.590</Result>
            <Result>41.621</Result>
            <Result>41.621</Result>
            <Result>26.875</Result>
            <Result>27.912</Result>
            <Result>29.607</Result>
            <Result>40.484</Result>
            <Result>39.827</Result>
            <Result>32.671</Result>
            <Result>22.234</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-15</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/16/2016</Date>
            <Result>25.410</Result>
            <Result>28.734</Result>
            <Result>34.607</Result>
            <Result>35.361</Result>
            <Result>35.580</Result>
            <Result>25.177</Result>
            <Result>26.487</Result>
            <Result>28.639</Result>
            <Result>42.086</Result>
            <Result>41.734</Result>
            <Result>32.560</Result>
            <Result>21.761</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-16</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/17/2016</Date>
            <Result>27.631</Result>
            <Result>29.734</Result>
            <Result>34.616</Result>
            <Result>41.450</Result>
            <Result>41.450</Result>
            <Result>27.165</Result>
            <Result>29.369</Result>
            <Result>30.090</Result>
            <Result>36.515</Result>
            <Result>35.767</Result>
            <Result>34.799</Result>
            <Result>21.890</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-17</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/18/2016</Date>
            <Result>25.241</Result>
            <Result>31.313</Result>
            <Result>32.417</Result>
            <Result>43.768</Result>
            <Result>43.649</Result>
            <Result>25.368</Result>
            <Result>28.130</Result>
            <Result>31.503</Result>
            <Result>37.349</Result>
            <Result>37.003</Result>
            <Result>34.086</Result>
            <Result>21.833</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-18</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/19/2016</Date>
            <Result>24.549</Result>
            <Result>27.268</Result>
            <Result>26.782</Result>
            <Result>37.610</Result>
            <Result>37.610</Result>
            <Result>23.636</Result>
            <Result>25.452</Result>
            <Result>27.363</Result>
            <Result>33.488</Result>
            <Result>32.651</Result>
            <Result>33.576</Result>
            <Result>21.442</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-19</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/20/2016</Date>
            <Result>17.883</Result>
            <Result>20.992</Result>
            <Result>20.503</Result>
            <Result>34.857</Result>
            <Result>34.857</Result>
            <Result>18.543</Result>
            <Result>25.680</Result>
            <Result>22.925</Result>
            <Result>31.672</Result>
            <Result>30.754</Result>
            <Result>32.830</Result>
            <Result>20.380</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-20</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/21/2016</Date>
            <Result>25.301</Result>
            <Result>32.263</Result>
            <Result>32.770</Result>
            <Result>35.996</Result>
            <Result>35.889</Result>
            <Result>25.152</Result>
            <Result>27.369</Result>
            <Result>31.490</Result>
            <Result>34.397</Result>
            <Result>34.980</Result>
            <Result>36.898</Result>
            <Result>21.706</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-21</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/22/2016</Date>
            <Result>28.422</Result>
            <Result>33.111</Result>
            <Result>34.305</Result>
            <Result>34.639</Result>
            <Result>34.317</Result>
            <Result>27.990</Result>
            <Result>29.109</Result>
            <Result>32.485</Result>
            <Result>34.369</Result>
            <Result>35.023</Result>
            <Result>37.596</Result>
            <Result>21.857</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-22</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/23/2016</Date>
            <Result>26.442</Result>
            <Result>30.177</Result>
            <Result>32.139</Result>
            <Result>30.111</Result>
            <Result>29.893</Result>
            <Result>27.974</Result>
            <Result>27.722</Result>
            <Result>30.000</Result>
            <Result>33.983</Result>
            <Result>34.055</Result>
            <Result>35.109</Result>
            <Result>21.740</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-23</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
        <ResultSet>
            <Date>03/24/2016</Date>
            <Result>27.784</Result>
            <Result>28.842</Result>
            <Result>31.024</Result>
            <Result>28.307</Result>
            <Result>28.307</Result>
            <Result>27.908</Result>
            <Result>28.035</Result>
            <Result>28.785</Result>
            <Result>31.508</Result>
            <Result>32.499</Result>
            <Result>33.318</Result>
            <Result>21.325</Result>
            <formatted-date-string>2016-03-24</formatted-date-string>
        </ResultSet>
    </DataSourceData>
    <profile-name>Spot Baseload</profile-name>
    <date-formats>
        <first-col-date-format>yyyy-MM-dd</first-col-date-format>
        <result-date-format>yyyy-MM-dd</result-date-format>
        <result-timestamp-format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</result-timestamp-format>
    </date-formats>
    <profile-settings />
    <profile-options>
        <start-date>2016-02-24</start-date>
        <precision>3</precision>
        <interval>Daily</interval>
        <sort-order>ASC</sort-order>
        <observe-dst>MERGED</observe-dst>
        <suppress-nulls>false</suppress-nulls>
        <end-date>2016-03-24</end-date>
    </profile-options>
    <group-name>Spot Prices</group-name>
</Profile>
```

Comment: `soup.findAll(ptdf_data1)` is incorrect: an argument of `findAll` should be tag name, you are putting the whole document there.

Comment: I think is better if you use Xpath and the lib lxml.

Comment: url or html code, please

Comment: Hi the XML code is here:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be better suited for comments, but i can't do that yet. There are three problems in your posted code:
1) Incorrect use of find_all, its argument should be a tag name. In your case, to obtain the relative information from the element `<DataSource>` you would want to correct the `find_all` to `soup.find_all("DataSource")` or from `<ResultSet>` you would do `soup.find_all("ResultSet")`, see the documentation on [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):
2) The tag calls you make from the suppossedly parsed document doesn't make sense, because as far as I see in the xml, they don't correspond to any element apart from the `Date` in the `ResultSet`. what you can do is either feed the exact location of your desired tag to a css selector, with `soup.select` method see [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) or you can use the `find` method if the structure of the tree permits a stable use of it, see [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find).
3) For taking the string out of the element, you can use `soup.get_text()` method, see [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text). Although the `.string` should also work if the child of the element is naviguable string, see [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string).

Once you dealt with these, especially once you show what elements correspond to your tag calls. We can see if we could workout a solution.